# Regex pattern for search first letters of the first and last name

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem with regex pattern. Every day I get names and surnames. Example:

```
    Darkholme Van Tadashi
    Herrington Billy Aniki
    Johny
    Walker Sam Cooler
    etc..
```

The fact is that they are specific and do not consist of just one last name and first name.

From this list, I need to select one person (whose last name and first name I know). To do this, I found pattern:

```
"Darkholme|\b[vt]"
```

As I said, I know the person's data in advance (before the list arrives). But I only know his last name. The second and third names (Van Tadashi) are unknown to me, I only know the first letters of these names ("V" and "T"). I ran into this problem: when regex analyzes incoming data (I use regex.ismatch), it returns true if the input string is "Van Dungeonmaster". How do I create a pattern that will only return true if the surname=Darkholme, first letters of the second and third names match (=V and T)?

Perhaps I'm not making myself clear.. But in the end, it should turn out that I passed only the last name and the first letters of the first name and patronymic to pattern, and regex gave a match for input string.

Comment: Assuming the names do not consists of a single char, like this? `\bDarkholme\s+[VT]\S+\s+[VT]\S+` https://regex101.com/r/ChPFt5/1

Comment: Right version of the list: Darkholme Van Tadashi, Herrington Billy Aniki, Johny Walker Sam Cooler, etc..

Comment: If there is a comma in the list and there can be 2 or 3 names following `\bDarkholme\s+[VT]\S+(?:\s+[VT]\S+)?(?=,|$)` https://regex101.com/r/W70VmA/1

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can I ask, in a case where the list contains only the last name and first name (Darkholme Van), how do I change your pattern so that it finds matches? In other words, the patronymic may be omitted, but the first letter of the patronymic will be passed in pattern.

Comment: The second pattern has an optional 3rd group, so if there is only Darkholme Van it will also match https://regex101.com/r/rHuQp2/1

Comment: If the order is V and then T, you could still use the optional group without the character class `\bDarkholme\s+V\S+(?:\s+T\S+)?` https://regex101.com/r/htCXT3/1

Comment: That is good, which one?

Comment: \bDarkholme\s+[VT]\S+(?:\s+[VT]\S+)?(?=,|$) and \bDarkholme\s+V\S+(?:\s+T\S+)? - thank you for pattern!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a comma present and the names can start with either V or T where the third name can be optional, you could use an optional group matching any non whitespace char except a comma.

```
\bDarkholme\s+[VT][^\s,]+(?:\s+[VT][^\s,]+)?
```

- `\b` Word bounary, to prevent Darkholme being part of a larger word
- `Darkholme` Match literally
- `\s+[VT]` Match 1+ whitespace chars followed by either V or T
- `[^\s,]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or comma
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s+[VT]` Match 1+ whitespace chars followed by either V or T
  - `[^\s,]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or comma
- `)?` Close the group to make the 3rd part optional

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbDarkholme%5cs%2b%5bVT%5d%5b%5e%5cs%2c%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5cs%2b%5bVT%5d%5b%5e%5cs%2c%5d%2b%29%3f&i=Darkholme+Van+Tadashi%0d%0aDarkholme+Van%0d%0aHerrington+Billy+Aniki%0d%0aJohny%0d%0aWalker+Sam+Cooler%0d%0a%0d%0aDarkholme+Van+Tadashi%2c+Herrington+Billy+Aniki%2c+Johny+Walker+Sam+Cooler%2c%0d%0aDarkholme+Van%2c+Herrington+Billy+Aniki%2c+Johny+Walker+Sam+Cooler%2c)

If you know that the name starts with V for the second and T for the third:

```
\bDarkholme\s+V[^\s,]+(?:\s+T[^\s,]+)?
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbDarkholme%5cs%2bV%5b%5e%5cs%2c%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5cs%2bT%5b%5e%5cs%2c%5d%2b%29%3f&i=Darkholme+Van+Tadashi%0d%0aDarkholme+Van%0d%0aHerrington+Billy+Aniki%0d%0aJohny%0d%0aWalker+Sam+Cooler%0d%0a%0d%0aDarkholme+Van+Tadashi%2c+Herrington+Billy+Aniki%2c+Johny+Walker+Sam+Cooler%2c%0d%0aDarkholme+Van%2c+Herrington+Billy+Aniki%2c+Johny+Walker+Sam+Cooler%2c)

If the name can also be a Single V or T, the quantifier could be an asterix for `[^\s,]*`

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern as is means "match any string that contains `Darkholme` or any string where any word starts with a `v` or a `t`" which isn't quite what you want

Perhaps

```
Darkholme\s+V\S*\s+T
```

Would suit you better. It means "darkholme followed by at least one white space then V, followed by any number of non whitespace characters then any number of whitespace followed by T

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can I ask, in a case where the list contains only the last name and first name (Darkholme Van), how do I change your pattern so that it finds matches? In other words, the patronymic may be omitted, but the first letter of the patronymic will be passed in pattern.

Comment: `Darkholme\s+V` then; it appears that finding the T is not useful